# Beamer option definition

Tags: beamer, options

Hi I'm building from scratch a new beamer theme. I would like to define an option in the theme where I can define the conference name which can be used afterwards for the footline. Up to now I've done the following. In the main theme I've defined

```
\DeclareOptionBeamer{conference}{\PassOptionsToPackage{conference=#1}{beamerouterthememytheme}}
```

and in the `beameroutermytheme.sty` I've defined the following

```
\def\beamer@mytheme@conference{}
\DeclareOptionBeamer{conference}{\def\beamer@mytheme@conference{#1}}
```

In the footline I've done the following

```
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{mytheme}[1]{
\begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=0.15\paperwidth,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm,sep=0.1cm]{footlinecolor}
\usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}%
\insertshortauthor~-~\@date~-~\beamer@mytheme@conference \hfill 
\insertframenumber{}/\inserttotalframenumber{}
\end{beamercolorbox}%
}
```

Unfortunately it does not work although I can't understand why.

Any suggestion?

As asked I try to provide a working example. Actually I hope it works as I've done definition for all inner,outer,color and main theme. In any case the file theme beamerthemeMytheme.sty sounds like

```
\mode<presentation>
\RequirePackage{pgf}
\DeclareOptionBeamer{conference}{\PassOptionsToPackage{conference=#1}{beamerouterthememytheme}}
\DeclareOptionBeamer{pageofpages} 
{\PassOptionsToPackage{pageofpages=#1} 
{beamerouterthememytheme}}
\ProcessOptionsBeamer
\useoutertheme{mytheme}
\mode
<all>
```

The file beameroutermytheme.sty sounds like

```
\mode<presentation>
\RequirePackage{pgf}

% efda colors
\definecolor{eblue}{rgb}{.258,.38,0.63}
\definecolor{e2blue}{rgb}{0.411,0.521,0.709}
% horizontal shading for footer
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{beamer@topshade}{\paperwidth}{% 
color(0pt)=(eblue); 
color(0.5\paperwidth)=(eblue!50);
color(\paperwidth)=(e2blue!50)}

% define the heigth of the footer
\newlength{\beamer@mytheme@headheight}
\setlength\beamer@mytheme@headheight{0.13\paperwidth}
%for date definition
\def\date#1{\def\@date{#1}}
% for page counting
\def\beamer@mytheme@pageofpages{of} 
\DeclareOptionBeamer{pageofpages}
{\def\beamer@mytheme@pageofpages{#1}} 
\ExecuteOptionsBeamer{pageofpages=of} 
\ProcessOptionsBeamer
\def\beamer@mytheme@conference{}
\DeclareOptionBeamer{conference}{\def\beamer@mytheme@conference{#1}}
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{mytheme}[1]
{%
\begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{\paperwidth}
  {0.3\beamer@mytheme@headheight} 
  \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}
    {0.3\beamer@mytheme@headheight}} \pgfusepath{clip}
  \pgftext [ left , base ]{\pgfuseshading{beamer@topshade}}
\end{pgfpicture}
\vskip-0.3\beamer@mytheme@headheight
\begin{beamercolorbox}    [ht=0.3\beamer@mytheme@headheight,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm,sep=0.1cm]{footlinecolor}
\usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}%
\insertshortauthor~-~\@date~-~\beamer@mytheme@conference \hfill 
\insertframenumber{}\hskip1pt\beamer@mytheme@pageofpages{}
\hskip1pt\inserttotalframenumber{}
\end{beamercolorbox}%
}
```

Finally the example is the following

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[conference=Prova]{mytheme}
\title[Prova]{Prova}
\author[myself]{Io}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Prerequisites \& Goals}
\begin{block}{LaTeX}
\begin{itemize}
\item Obviously some basic LaTeX knowledge is necessary
\item Some more features will be provided here
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably because you defined `\beamer@jet@conference` and later you tried to use it as `\beamer@mytheme@conference`

Comment: Sorry the definition is consistent. Only in the question I prefer to avoid the real name of the theme. I've edited the question consistently. By the way in this way I think that the -1 vote can be avoided

Comment: @NicolaVianello Please, try and show a real MWE. As it stands the question is not answerable.

Comment: I noticed you edit your question. I think the problem arises when you defined `\beamer@mytheme@conference{}` and the consequent option after `\ProcessOptionsBeamer` in your outer theme.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let us suppose you named your main file `beamerthemeX.sty`. There you place your option as:

```
\DeclareOptionBeamer{conference}{\PassOptionsToPackage{conference=#1}{beamerouterthemeX}}
\ProcessOptionsBeamer
```

Then in your `beamerouterthemeX.sty`:

```
\DeclareOptionBeamer{conference}{\def\beamer@X@conference{#1}}    
\ProcessOptionsBeamer
```

initially to define the option, while for the `footline`:

```
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{X theme}[1]{
\begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=0.15\paperwidth,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm,sep=0.1cm]{Location bar}
\usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}%
\insertshortauthor~-~\@date~-~\beamer@X@conference \hfill 
\insertframenumber{}/\inserttotalframenumber{}
\end{beamercolorbox}%
}
```

Now your `presentation.tex` will call:

```
\usetheme[conference=Name]{X}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot now it works. As far as I can understand I've forgotten the command \ProcessOptionsBeamer in the outer theme

Comment: Exactly: you placed `\ProcessOptionsBeamer` before another option declaration.

Comment: Note that you should put the `\PassOptionToPackage` before loading the outer theme.