# How to pass text/strings from main file to beamertheme via beameroptions or is there an alternative way?

Tags: beamer, macros

In [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240010/how-to-define-commands-for-additonal-information-in-beamer-main-file-for-use-in) and [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51651/beamer-option-definition) I learned how to pass simple definitions like a **location** from my main file to a e.g. **beameroutertheme**.

However this approach fails for longer strings or text blocks, in this example

***"Hello World!"***

---

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\author{George Orwell}
\title{Animal Farm}
\date{\today}
\institute[TUD]

\usetheme[myText=Hello World!]{tudrobert}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

which can then be used in the template definitions:

**beamerthemetudrobert.tex**

```
\mode<presentation>

\DeclareOptionBeamer{myText}{\PassOptionsToPackage{myText=#1}{beamerinnerthemetudrobert}}
\ProcessOptionsBeamer

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\useinnertheme{tudrobert}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]  

\mode<all>
```

And finally the theme where I'd like to insert the text:

**beamerinnerthemetudrobert.tex**

```
\mode<presentation>

\DeclareOptionBeamer{myText}{\def\beamer@tudrobert@myText{#1}}    
\ProcessOptionsBeamer

\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{tudrobert}{%

    \usebeamerfont*{title}
    \MakeUppercase{\inserttitle}\par
    \vfill
    {\scriptsize\insertauthor}
    \vfill
    \beamer@tudrobert@myText
    \vfill
    \insertdate

}

\mode<all>
```

---

As you can see, the text is not parsed correctly.

[image]

**What is the appropriate way to pass text defined in the main file to beamer themes?**

Comment: Not a good way, but as a workaround I use otherwise unused fields. For example I wanted to add a conference location and stored it in the subtitle which my theme not uses otherwise. Than I can simply insert it with `\insertsubtitle`

Comment: @samcarter I don't have any unused fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following answer is based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58512/36296 and the author definition in latex.ltx

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme[myText=Hello World!]{tudrobert}

\author{George Orwell}
\title{Animal Farm}
\date{\today}
\institute[TUD]
\def\uni{Hello World!}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**beamerthemetudrobert.tex**

```
\mode<presentation>

\DeclareOptionBeamer{myText}{\PassOptionsToPackage{myText=#1}{beamerinnerthemetudrobert}}
\ProcessOptionsBeamer

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{calc}

\def\uni#1{\gdef\@uni{#1}}
\def\@uni{\@latex@warning@no@line{No \noexpand\uni given}}

\useinnertheme{tudrobert}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]  

\mode<all>
```

**beamerinnerthemetudrobert.tex**

```
\mode<presentation>

\DeclareOptionBeamer{myText}{\def\beamer@tudrobert@myText{#1}}    
\ProcessOptionsBeamer

\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{tudrobert}{%

    \usebeamerfont*{title}
    \MakeUppercase{\inserttitle}\par
    \vfill
    {\scriptsize\insertauthor}
    \vfill
    \beamer@tudrobert@myText
    \vfill
    \insertdate
    \vfill
    \@uni

}

\mode<all>
```

[image]

Comment: But I am not really sure why I need the `\def` in `main.tex`

Comment: me neither, I lost the thread trying to understand how these inter-class-macros work.

Comment: @thewaywewalk Just copy pasted them :)